# Android USB protocols

Tags: android, usb

I have read about the Android Open Accessory Protocol, but I want to make an android accessory that isn't the USB Host device, but where the Android device has USB on the go and is the USB host, and my designed accessory is the USB accessory.

Will the Android Open Accessory Protocol support this? Or will it only support a device that is the USB host?

Thanks for your time,

James

Comment: No, it will not.  But for the case you want, you would write code within your application to perform the USB operations required by the peripheral device you want to connect.  If you are only designing the peripheral now, consider something easily supported not only on Android but on a PC as well, as that will make your testing much, much simpler.  For very simple needs, one of the various serial-over-USB schemes can be popular.